# VS Code - Oracle Dev Tools - Encountered the symbol "/" (forward slash)

Tags: oracle, visual-studio-code, plsql, compiler-errors

#### Description

myScript.sql contains package spec and body with "/" after each as:

```sql
CREATE OR UPDATE PACKAGE myPackage AS
    ...
END myPackage;
/

CREATE OR UPDATE PACKAGE BODY myPackage AS
    ...
END myPackage;
/
```

#### Using Oracle SQL Developer:

If I open myScript.sql and Use the "Run Script (F5)" option:

In the Script Output I see the package compiles successfully with:

```
Package myPackage compiled


Package Body myPackage compiled
```

#### Using the VS Code's Oracle Developer Tools Extension:

If I open myScript.sql and use the "Execute All (Ctrl+R)" option:

In the script results I see the package fails to compile with:

```
ORA-24344: success with compilation error
PACKAGE created.

Commit complete.
```

And in the problems tab I see `PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "/"`

UPDATE: After the compilation fails I opened the package spec from the database and can see the ENTIRE package body is being included... (this does not occur when the same file is run from SQL Developer)

I think this is because plsql is expecting the body and the spec to be defined in different queries... it seems "/" is somewhat of an end-of-file symbol meant to separate calls somehow...

#### Request:

According [this page](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqpug/slash.html#GUID-F5EEC10C-6E74-4CCE-A196-C591F83C3D44) from oracle it seems the slash is a command that actually executes what's currently in the SQL buffer.

I'm not sure why the Oracle Dev Tools extension is interpreting the "/" symbol differently than SQL Developer but it's a pretty major blocker as the usage is common practice throughout my team's codebase.

#### Update:

As MT0 pointed out this symbol isn't an end-of-file symbol but instead it is a **BLOCK** terminator as mentioned [here](https://docs.oracle.com/database/sql-developer-17.4/SQCQR/toc.htm#SQCQR-GUID-CD559E5B-FDC3-40DA-B699-E2EBFC4C5D9B) and [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqpug/SET-system-variable-summary.html#GUID-2967B311-24CB-43E0-95F2-BFC429CF033D)...

After some trial and error **I was able to get the script to compile** by adding the following line to the top of the file.

```
SET BLOCKTERMINATOR /
```

Still need to research how safe this change is and also how to set it on launch but at least it's a start...

Comment: The documentation you link to is for the SQL\*Plus client application and is **NOT** for the Oracle database. If you use `/` in SQL\*Plus then it will execute the the most recently executed command OR what's currently in the SQL buffer and will send the command to the database to be parsed and executed but SQL\*Plus does not send the `/` statement terminator (because it is not part of the command, it is the terminator that tells the client to send the command).

Comment: "if I open myPackage from the database the "/" symbols are present with red squiggles underneath." That is syntax highlighting in the VS code client application and is (again) **NOT** from the database. The `PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "/"` is from the database, are you sure you clicked "Execute All" and did not have everything highlighted and clicked "Execute SQL"? If you "Execute SQL" then it will send the current statement to the database and if you have everything selected then it will send the entire script including the statement terminators which will then cause syntax errors.

Comment: @MT0 Yes I am sure I am clicking "Execute All" button from the Oracle Dev Tooltip (top right) which I can also call using Ctrl+R. After looking more closely I also noticed the ENTIRE package body is being stuffed into the package spec which is obviously causing problems... It seems like "/" is more like an end-of-file symbol because technically in plsql you're supposed to split the spec/body into two files...

Comment: updated the OP with a better description of the problem and symptoms.

Comment: `/` is not an end-of-file symbol. It is a PL/SQL statement terminator (used on a new line) that tells clients when a PL/SQL statement terminates. The VS code client should parse your script into individual statements and pass them to the database one-by-one for it to run and do that by looking for the statement terminators (`;` or `/` for SQL statements and `/` for PL/SQL statement). Whatever you are doing, it appears to be passing the entire script and not individual statements. It is probably a configuration error somewhere on your client but there is not enough information to tell where.

Comment: To clarify, the Oracle database expects each command passed to it to be a single SQL or PL/SQL statement which is why if the client passes a script with multiple statements it causes a syntax error (since the statement terminator is not part of the statement and the database considers its presence to be invalid syntax). This is not an Oracle database issue, it is a client-side issue in that for some reason (whether it be your actions or the clients configuration) that the client is not separating the script into individual statements based on the statement terminators.

Comment: @MT0 thank you for taking the time to explain the purpose and function of the "/" symbol. After doing some more research I found you to be correct "/" is indeed a terminator but it's a BLOCK terminator not a STATEMENT terminator (like ;). My workaround for now is to add `SET BLOCKTERMINATOR OFF` at the top of the file... still researching how safe this is and how to automate. Please see the updated section in my OP

Comment: We are just using different terminology for the same thing. An executable PL/SQL statement is a "block" (typically an anonymous block as a non-anonymous block would be a package, function, procedure or type and they aren't normally referred to as blocks but by their more specific name). I suggest you add your solution as a self-answer to the question (rather than including it in the question) as self-answers are accepted (and encouraged).

Comment: @MT0 I believe you are mistaken, in PL/SQL a statement/command and a block are two distinct concepts. A block may consist of multiple commands and is ended with a "/" on a new line (as indicated here: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqpug/using-scripts-in-SQL-Plus.html#GUID-E9305EF3-85CF-49BF-AB4D-E2BBBA2C8025)

Comment: It *looks* like the statement terminator is controlled via `SET SQLTERMINATOR` where are the block terminator is controlled via `SET BLOCKTERMINATOR`

Comment: I'm still working on a permanent configuration change to the client before marking this as answered. adding a new line to every piece of code in production is not a viable solution I owe that to myself and anyone else who stumbles across this page

Comment: I've updated the OP... apparently it was `SET BLOCKTERMINATOR /`

Comment: ... this is getting more and more bizzare... apprently the true culprit is cases with an uneven number of quotes in the comments of a block... like
```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE TEMP AS
PROCEDURE myProcedure(
p_customer_first -- this is a comment '
,p_customer_last -- this is a comment
);
END TEMP;
/
```

^ This compiles in SQL Developer but not Oracle Dev Tools... I've submitted a bug report here: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Oracle.oracledevtools&ssr=false#qna

Answer (score 1):

After significantly more troubleshooting I found I had misdiagnosed the issue entirely... by default the block terminator "/" was functioning properly however single quotes within these blocks were failing

This works:

```
SELECT * FROM DUAL -- '
```

This works:

```
SELECT * FROM DUAL -- ''
/
```

This doesn't:

```
SELECT * FROM DUAL -- '
/
```

I've submitted a new question with this information here: [VS Code - Oracle Dev Tools: Single quote in comments break block terminator symbol "/" (slash)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77602687/vs-code-oracle-dev-tools-single-quote-in-comments-break-block-terminator-symb)