# VS Code - Oracle Dev Tools: Single quote in comments break block terminator symbol "/" (slash)

Tags: oracle, visual-studio-code, plsql, sqlplus

Having a weird issue with the Oracle Dev Tools Extension for VS Code. The "/" (slash) symbol breaks if there's an uneven number of quotes in the block. It works fine in SQL Developer but with the VS Code extension it returns with `Encountered the symbol "/"`

This compiles just fine...

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE CUSTOMER_PKG AS
PROCEDURE ADDCUSTOMER(
P_FIRST_NAME IN VARCHAR2 -- Customer's first name
,P_LAST_NAME IN VARCHAR2 -- Customer's last name
);
END CUSTOMER_PKG;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY CUSTOMER_PKG AS
PROCEDURE ADDCUSTOMER(
P_FIRST_NAME IN VARCHAR2 -- Customer's first name
,P_LAST_NAME IN VARCHAR2 -- Customer's last name
) AS
BEGIN
NULL;
END ADDCUSTOMER;
END CUSTOMER_PKG;
/
```

But this returns with `PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "/"`

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE CUSTOMER_PKG AS
PROCEDURE ADDCUSTOMER(
P_FIRST_NAME IN VARCHAR2 -- Customer's first name
,P_LAST_NAME IN VARCHAR2 -- Customers last name
);
END CUSTOMER_PKG;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY CUSTOMER_PKG AS
PROCEDURE ADDCUSTOMER(
P_FIRST_NAME IN VARCHAR2 -- Customer's first name
,P_LAST_NAME IN VARCHAR2 -- Customers last name
) AS
BEGIN
NULL;
END ADDCUSTOMER;
END CUSTOMER_PKG;
/
```

Here's another example...

This works:

```sql
SELECT * FROM DUAL -- '
```

This works:

```sql
SELECT * FROM DUAL -- ''
/
```

This doesn't:

```sql
SELECT * FROM DUAL -- '
/
```

Keep in mind **ALL** examples run in SQL Developer without an issue... I need Oracle Dev Tools to compile like Oracle SQL Developer does as this is what our codebase is built off of.

this is a major blocker as it's very common in our codebase to combine the spec and body into the same file using "/" to separate the two... and these often contain (an uneven number of) quotes within the comments...

I've been digging through the SQL*PLUS config settings to see if there's some setting to fix this but haven't found anything yet...

Comment: This is nothing that SQL\*Plus commands can fix. This is a bug with the VS Code extension as it should not be matching quotes within comments. The extension needs to parse the script and identify the individual statements within the script and then open a transaction with the database and send the statements to the database one-by-one within that transaction. It appears that the extension is incorrectly parsing the script so that it is failing to identify when the statement terminators occur and instead is looking for a closing single quote which it should never have started trying to match.

Comment: ... and in looking for that closing single quote is skipping over the statement terminator it should have found which means that the statement terminator is included in the command sent to the database which, from the database's point-of-view, is a syntax error.

Comment: Thank you @MT0 I've opened a Q&A on the visual studio marketplace to see if I can get support from Oracle on this.

Answer (score 1):

I posted this as a bug report in the Q&A on the visual studio marketplace. Oracle responded by saying this will be fixed in the next release (21.8) available later this month.

You can see this here: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Oracle.oracledevtools&ssr=false#qna